# Compare text and string Jquery

Tags: jquery, string, properties, comparison

```js
let teste = $('.btn-timer').text().trim();

  condition = '15:00'

  //let result = teste.localeCompare(condition);
  //console.log(result);

  if (teste == condition) {
      $('.btn-timer').removeClass('btn-success');
      $('.btn-timer').addClass('btn-danger');
  }

  console.log(teste);
  console.log(condition);
```

```css
 .btn-danger {
        color: #991C32 !important;
        background-color: #FFB2C0 !important;
        border-color: #C82442 !important;
    }

    .btn-success {
        color: #234D31 !important;
        background-color: #B2FFCD !important;
        border-color: #449560 !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-success shadow btn-timer td-content">
  <b>15:00</b>
</button>
```

I'am trying to implement a code that compare a text() from class with a string:

I tried a lot of things, but without luck, any help?

What I am doing wrong? and how to fiz it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please add the HTML of `.btn-timer`.

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/wqso9f23/2/

Comment: Do you have multiple `.btn-timer` elements? You're just getting the text of the first one. If you want to process each one separately, you should use `.each()` loop.

Comment: As above: code, *as provided* with some assumptions regarding `btn-timer` and the success/danger classes, works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/z9q2Lypk/

Comment: *What I am doing wrong?* - well, your edit appears to show... nothing wrong at all - it works fine as described.  What are you *expecting to happen*?

Comment: I have a lot of then, in that case, how can I take not just the first, but all of then?

Comment: *I have a lot of them* - there's no reference to more than one in the question.  Please be clear what your issue actually is.   Looks like @Barmar has used their experience and correctly *guessed* this is your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following example, for multiple buttons of the same class.

```js
$(function() {

  // Set Condition
  var condition = '15:00';

  $('.btn-timer').each(function(i, el) {
    // Test the element "el" Text against the Condition 
    if ($(el).text().trim() == condition) {
      // Remove class and add new class
      $(el).toggleClass('btn-success btn-danger');
    }
    console.log($(el).text().trim(), condition);
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-danger {
  color: #991C32 !important;
  background-color: #FFB2C0 !important;
  border-color: #C82442 !important;
}

.btn-success {
  color: #234D31 !important;
  background-color: #B2FFCD !important;
  border-color: #449560 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-success shadow btn-timer td-content">
  <b>14:00</b>
</button>
<button class="btn btn-success shadow btn-timer td-content">
  <b>15:00</b>
</button>
<button class="btn btn-success shadow btn-timer td-content">
  <b>16:00</b>
</button>
```

Using `.each()` we can iterate each element. See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/each/
- https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

You can also use a more direct Selector.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn-timer:contains('15:00')").toggleClass("btn-success btn-danger");
});
```

```css
.btn-danger {
  color: #991C32 !important;
  background-color: #FFB2C0 !important;
  border-color: #C82442 !important;
}

.btn-success {
  color: #234D31 !important;
  background-color: #B2FFCD !important;
  border-color: #449560 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-success shadow btn-timer td-content">
  <b>14:00</b>
</button>
<button class="btn btn-success shadow btn-timer td-content">
  <b>15:00</b>
</button>
<button class="btn btn-success shadow btn-timer td-content">
  <b>16:00</b>
</button>
```

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/